# How to Connect to Hostgator Database instead of Localhost

Tags: php

I am stuck with this problem with my hosted website. My problem is that instead of connecting to Hostgator's File Manager, I am connected to My Computer instead that's why I can login to my website just like localhost. I contacted Hostgator and even they could not solve this issue because one of their Web Advisor said this to me: `I checked the errors and I could see that the requests are considering the hostname 'localhost' as the URL due to which you are experiencing the issue. You would need to check the script and fix the issue`. When I changed my credentials in localhost,  I am getting this error: `Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'myHostgatorusername'@'mycomputerip' (using password: YES) in myComputerFileLocation on line 323`

Are my scripts correct? Should I change my localhost to something like my Site's IP? I tried it but it doesn't work for me.

ConnectDb.php

```
<?php

namespace Classes;

class ConnectDb
{
    function Connect()
    {
        return new \MysqliDb(array(
            'host' => 'myHostgatorsiteip',
            'username' => 'myHostgatorusername',
            'password' => 'myHostgatorpassword',
            'db' => 'mydatabase',
            'port' => 3306,
            'prefix' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8'
        ));
    }
}
```

index.js

```
 LOGIN (context, payload) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios
            .post('http://localhost/MyComposer/', payload, {
              headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
              params: {
                submitId: 3
              }
            })
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response.data)

              if (response.data === '') {
                resolve(response)
              }

              for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                const token = response.data[i].AccessId
                if (
                  response.data.Username === payload.Username &&
                  response.data.Password === payload.Password
                ) {
                  localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
                  context.commit('accessToken', token)
                  resolve(response)
                }
              }
            })
            .catch(error => {
              reject('Login Error!')
              console.log(error)
            })
        })
      },
```

Comment: Do you use Plesk or CPanel?

Comment: I use Cpanel. By the way, after debugging for a few hours, I decided to changed my URL's into my domain name instead of localhost now (as instructed by my co-worker)